# ServerAsyncReaderWriter.Write is not async which performs tcp_write

Tags: grpc

grpc version 1.26.0

language: c++

os: centos 7

As an async bidi streaming server, I expect ServerAsyncReaderWriter::Write is async, the actual work(say tcp_write/flush) would be done mostly in the background(maybe the default executor).

But actually, perf(perf record -F 99 -p xx -g -- sleep 90) shows ServerAsyncReaderWriter::Write directly calls tcp_write, and the default executor is almost idle all the time.

Walking down the source along ServerAsyncReaderWriter::Write -> Call::PerformOps -> Server::PerformOpsOnCall -> CallOpSet::FillOps -> grpc_call_start_batch -> ~ExecCtx -> ExecCtx::Flush -> grpc_combiner_continue_exec_ctx, I don't find any chance to give work to others...

Is this by design, or what's wrong?

[image: flamegraph of ServerAsyncReaderWriter::Write]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks to work as intended. gRPC C++ tries to use the given threads as much as possible. It uses another threads such only when it has to.

Comment: thanks. Is there any official documents or comments mention this?